# Setting AUTOCOMMIT=0/1 on the global level does not seem to have any effect in MariaDB 10.3

Tags: mariadb, autocommit

I am an Oracle guy currently learning MariaDB and MySQL. I am running MariaDB 10.3.

To my surprise, the changes I make in session 1 without first starting a transaction are immediately visible for session 2 even when I set AUTOCOMMIT=0 on the global level. And conversely, the changes made within a transaction in session 1 are not visible for session 2 until I explicitly commit the transaction - even when I set AUTOCOMMIT=1 on the global level. So, I am currently under impression that setting of AUTOCOMMIT on the global level does not produce any effect in MariaDB version 10.3.

Note: setting AUTOCOMMIT on the session level seems to be working properly. For example, when I say SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT=0, MariaDB implicitly starts a new transaction when the previous transaction ends; therefore, the changes I make in session 1 become visible for session 2 only after an explicit commit and I do not have to worry about explicitly  starting new transactions - exactly how it is done in Oracle.

I would like all my sessions to have this behavior by default, without having to set AUTOCOMMIT=0 explicitly for each of them. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the value of `transaction_isolation`?  Setting a `GLOBAL` does _not_ change the value of the equivalent `SESSION` variable for any currently logged in connections.

Comment: I figured it out. I had this problem because I re-started mariadb service after I set autocommit=0. So, my setting was wiped-out and the server got back to the default setting autocommit=1. I did not notice that. Now, I changed this setting in /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf: `[mysqld]
autocommit=0`

Comment: I've also set transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED at the same place. Now, I am happy: everything is like in Oracle :)